# Libsvm alyways predicting the same class

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I'm using Libsvm to resolve a binary classification problem. My dataset has ~50K attributes and 18 samples. I'm using a leave one out validation (training on 17 samples and test on the remaining sample). I'm normalizing the data by using:

```
svm-scale -s scaling_parameters Train$i > TrainScaled$i
svm-scale -r scaling_parameters Test$i > TestScaled$i
```

the training and the prediction is done as:

```
svm-train -s 0 -c 5 -t 2 -g 0.5 -e 0.1 TrainScaled$i model
svm-predict TestScaled$i model predicted.out
```

The model always predict the same class (majority one). So I obtain 75% accuracy, but the model is useless because it always predict the same class for each sample. I tried different type of kernels and paramenters but I still have the same result. What could it be? Are the data so hard to "divided" by the hyperplane?

Comment: My dataset has ~50K attributes and 18 samples　I think you need more sample to train a model, you can try to analysis is there any feature in the 50K dimensions will help in discriminate the two class in you sample

Comment: I tried to apply a feature selection but nothing changed, even applying a drastic reduction to only 100 attributes

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that given the ratio of features to classes, that your algorithm may be overfitting your input even with a significant amount of regularization.  Have you tried using dimensionality reduction techniques such as PCA and working with a smaller number of features?  You could also try some sort of feature selection algorithm to get a small subset of features.

Comment: I tried to apply a feature selection but nothing changed, even applying a drastic reduction to only 100 attributes

Comment: Try training with one feature at a time and see what happens

Comment: Even with one feature...always predicting the same class (majority class)

Comment: Is it possible that the features have no signal?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem in my application, I used libsvm in my c++ project to perform binary classification, but **it always predicts only one class for all samples**.

The followings are some information about my application.

(1) I have 260 training samples in total and set 80% for train and cross validation, and 20% for test.

(2) While **number of my features is 7218**, which is much bigger than the sample number.

(3) For binary classification, my class labels are set as 0 and 1.

After repeated trials, I found that the failure of SVM classification in my application is primarily caused by the **inefficiency of used features**, which makes the overfitting of SVM classification model, **especially when there are large amounts of features**.